# Eclipse LogCat unreadable - OpenCV / Android NDK

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv, android-ndk

I'm pretty new to Eclipse and Android dev and only recently installed NDK and OpenCV and ever since I've been battling. Win8/Eclipse Juno/NDK R8D/OpenCV 2.4.4

Project folder has this red exclamation mark but no files within are showing any errors.
CDT builds the app just fine!
Here's what LogCat gives me:

Any clue? Cheers

EDIT:
after I followed your advise I ended up with the following:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Project 'OpenCV Library - 2.4.4' is missing required library: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-17\android.jar' OpenCV Library - 2.4.4      Build path  Build Path Problem
The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Android\android-opencv-2-4-4\sdk\java\bin\opencv library - 2.4.4.jar'  Test1       Build path  Build Path Problem
```

Comment: If you right click the project in eclipse and choose properties > android, you will see a list of android api levels available in your sdk. If 17 is not there, try ticking the highest api level you have, although opencv may have a specific api level requirement. If that doesn't work you will need to open your android sdk manager and update to get the latest platform version api levels. Once updated repeat steps above.

Comment: For the Android Dependencies issue, if you choose properties > java build path and choose the libraries tab, you should be able to remove the erroneous entry and choosing 'add external jars' should be able to import the required opencv jar, although you'l have to locate this on your computer first.

Comment: The whole Bin folder is missing from the open cv library , I unpacked it twice , still no difference

Comment: Is the opencv library an android project? If so you'll need to import the opencv project into eclipse, select it and go to project in the top menu, select clean, then select build project. Building the project will generate the bin and gen folders.

Comment: Cleaning selected projects has encountered a problem.

Comment: Alright, finally got it to work. Reimported opencv, assigned it a project build target and then was finally able to build it / clean it. Thanks for all your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the project folder is showing a red exclamation mark, try going to window > show view > problems and there may be a better description there of any problems.

The log above looks like a general log from your device. If you want to log from a specific running application, run the app on a device from eclipse and type app:com.yourpackagename in the text field above the LogCat output.

Comment: Thanks man, this helped although I now have to face 8 different errors :)

Comment: Thanks again. Alright, so the first one - 17 is there. But when I navigate to the actual folder outside Eclipse, this file is indeed not there. As per the second one; dependencies - I tried to add external JAR but there is no such file in my OpenCV folder. So I don't seem to locate any JAR files whatsoever.

Comment: You could try adding Opencv as a library to your project within eclipse. So assuming you have imported an opencv library project into eclipse and you have new android project that you want to use opencv with... select your project, right click > properties > android, under the project build target api list is the library panel, click add and select the imported open cv library. The open cv project has to have been imported into eclipse for this to work. Also worth double checking, right click the opencv project, go to the same area as mentioned above and check 'is library' is ticked. good luck

Comment: then clean and build opencv, following that clean and build your project

Comment: In my project , there is an OpenCV library assigned to it, although if I go to OpenCV libraries there is nothing in the box , if I want to add a library to openCV, I can only add my own application...